# keep getting this message: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function

Tags: pine-script

What is wrong with the code that I keep getting this error message?
I get the error message only when I add the last line

```
    CondIni = 0

longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
if ma_opt
    longCond := src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 or src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0
    shortCond := src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 or src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0
    CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1] 
    
longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

Reversal() => longCondition or shortCondition
//Alerts

scr_label = 'Reversal  \n-----------\n'
scr_label := s1  ? scr_label + 'NIU\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s2  ? scr_label + 'YALA\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s3  ? scr_label + 'TDC\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s4  ? scr_label + 'DKNG\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s5  ? scr_label + 'NUS\n' : scr_label

scr_label_before := s1  ? scr_label_before + 'NIU '  : scr_label_before
scr_label_before := s2  ? scr_label_before + 'YALA '  : scr_label_before
scr_label_before := s3  ? scr_label_before + 'TDC '  : scr_label_before
scr_label_before := s4  ? scr_label_before + 'DKNG '  : scr_label_before
scr_label_before := s5  ? scr_label_before + 'NUS ' : scr_label_before

lab_l1 = label.new(bar_index, low, scr_label, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_lower_left, yloc = yloc.price)
``
```

Comment: are you talking about the ``?

Comment: Please, visit the site below to know [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).